# How can I generate iOS code to draw an image?

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, compression, core-graphics

How can I consume a graphic and then generate objective-c code that can draw it? The code generation doesn't need to be written in objective-c, but must generate objective-c code.

Input: A.png

Output: Core Graphics code to generate a file A.png that would match the image of the original  file, A.png.

For example, since I can find out the color and position of every pixel, what tool can I use to write iOS code that draws those pixels exactly.

Why inflate the bundle size with images or why wait to pull down images from a web service when the app itself could generate those images with the right instructions.

My intention is to use this in a white label solution.

Comment: There is no way on earth code to write out a PNG pixel by pixel will be smaller than said PNG, compiled or not. What with PNG being an image compression format, that is a piece of software expressly designed with representing a pixel-by-pixel description of an image using as little data as possible.

Comment: Same for a vector image - my hunch is that compressed SVG, or better yet [PDF](http://mattgemmell.com/2012/02/10/using-pdf-images-in-ios-apps/) would be more compact than the ObjC code to draw it.

Comment: As far as I know iOS 7 still doesn't display svgs except in web views, so I see value in having an svg -> graphics layer code converter.

Comment: iOS can display PDFs natively--you could conceivably ZIP the file as well (assuming it isn't already using compression internally)

Answer (score 2):

> Why inflate the bundle size with images or why wait to pull down images from a web service when the app itself could generate those images with the right instructions

Because your code will still need to contain all the information contained in the image, plus all those drawing instructions, so you're going to end up with a larger product, not a smaller one. Additionally, building the image data into the code makes it that much harder to change.

Comment: Well, if the image has a certain symmetry, then it could be feasible to generate it by code. Demo coders do this all the time. E.g. the .kkrieger first person shooter ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.kkrieger ) takes up only 96 kbytes of disk space, in spite of employing quite rich textures and bump-maps.

Comment: @TamásZahola That's true, but it sounds to me like the OP is talking about generating code to draw arbitrary images, not generating parametric images. Consider: *I can find out the color and position of every pixel, what tool can I use to write iOS code that draws those pixels exactly.*

Answer (score 1):

Use [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/) to create your graphics. 
You are done.

Comment: can PaintCode take a png as input?

Comment: @kraftydevil - was my link to their web site not sufficient?

Comment: Almost - The specific use case I'm looking for is to import a PNG and then generate code to replicate it. If Paintcode can do this or something very similar (hard for me to tell as an graphics novice), please state this and maybe show how to accomplish this.